# Access JavaScript local storage from android

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova

I'm having a mobile Cordova application . I'm saving data in JavaScript local storage and i want to read/access same data in the local storage of Java. Can anybody help me on this or tell is it possible to do or not.

**Note :** I know how to access local storage in Java but i'm not able to access data which i saved in JavaScript local storage.

**Example :**

**JavaScript :**

`window.localStorage.setItem("UserName", "Jane");`

**Java :**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = CoreOneViewMobileActivity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String name= sharedPref.getString("UserName","none");
```

Comment: I think you can execute js from a `webview` probably

Comment: usually when there is a need to access the native storage of android or ios you are doing so using the `cordova-plugin-nativestorage`. The plugin will allow you to access SharedPreferences.

Comment: @ Sangeeta you got this ? how to get the values from android  ?

Comment: @Sangeeta bhatt did you solve the problem?
If you solve then can you please share the solution. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: I have solved this problem with https://stackoverflow.com/a/58452676/2131915